# Debugging node.js app in webstorm

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, webstorm

I have strange problem with node.js app. I can start it with grunt task, typing

```
grunt
```

in terminal, from project folder.
But when I try to start application from webstorm, I have an error

> Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task Fatal error: Error: not found:
>   node
>       Warning:  Used --force, continuing.
>
> ```
> Running "watch" task Waiting...
> ```

Webstorm configurations.

1. Node interpreter: {path to node}
2. Working directory: {path to project}
3. JavaScript file: {path to grunt}

Comment: Looks like node is not found in your PATH. What OS are you on? How do you run your application from WebStorm?

Comment: Yes I find problem, and added PATH in environment variables in WebStorm, but still have problem with debugging app which I start with grunt, I mean program doesn't see my breakpoints, works only when I start with "node server.js", I'll be happy if I can find any solution not debugging app started with grunt, only nodemon will be ok... 
OS - ubuntu 12.04. WebStorm version 7.0.

Comment: see [WEB-9126](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9126) - does it look similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the exact same problem and just now updating to the latest version of Webstorm has solved the problem for me. You said you're on version 7.0 so see if the upgrade helps you as well.

Have a look here for some more discussion.

I also had to make sure to set the remote paths in the JavaScript debug to avoid having extra windows pop up.